# Search pattern between tags in html

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I need to get value from a tag with specific title.

I have this command.

```
sed -n 's/title="view quote">\(.*\)<\/a>/\1/p' index.html
```

This is part of index.html and i need that 'Everything in life is luck'

```
    <a title="view quote" href="https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/donald_trump_106578" class="oncl_q">
<img id="qimage_106578" src="./Donald Trump Quotes - BrainyQuote_files/donaldtrump1.jpg" class="bqphtgrid" alt="Everything in life is luck. - Donald Trump">
</a>
</div>
<a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/donald_trump_106578" class="b-qt qt_106578 oncl_q" title="view quote">Everything in life is luck.</a>
<a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/donald_trump_106578" class="bq-aut qa_106578 oncl_a" title="view author">Donald Trump</a>
</div>
```

And i need all this vlaues to fill in array in bash.

Comment: `mapfile -t array < <(printf '%s\n' 'g/^<a.*title="view quote">\(.\{1,\}\)<\/a>/s//\1/p' Q | ed -s index.html)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sed command is mostly good - just missing `.*` at each end of regex to remove additional head and tail.

This command extract all values with your specific title:

```
sed -n 's/.*title="view quote">\(.*\)<\/a>.*/\1/p' index.html
```

To put into an array:

```
IFS=$'\n' array=( $(sed -n 's/.*title="view quote">\(.*\)<\/a>.*/\1/p' index.html) )
```

To verify your result array:

```
for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++)); do
    echo ${array[$i]}
done
```